# Is there a js callback for when youtube player begins again after pausing to buffer?

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to figure out if there is a callback for when the player is **not** buffering anymore.

I'm using  `onPlayerBuffering: function(){};` right now for when the player begins buffering, but I can't seem to find anything that does the opposite.

the `onPlayerPlaying: function(){};` doesn't seem to work once the player buffers.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Also, i'm using  [Nirvana Tikku 's jquery-youtube pluggin](http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin), a list of the callbacks [are here](http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin#tubeplayer_tutorial_3) and [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Overview)...Would none of these do the job?

THANKS!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ckeck out the YouTube player API https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events

You just have to listen to the `onStateChange` event:

Here's a working demo: http://jsbin.com/izolo/edit

sample code:

```
function handlePlayerStateChange (state) {
  switch (state) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
      // Video has begun playing/buffering
      videoContainer.cycle('pause');
      break;
    case 2:
    case 0:
      // Video has been paused/ended
      videoContainer.cycle('resume');
      break;
  }
}

function onYouTubePlayerReady(id){
  var player = $('#' + id)[0];
  if (player.addEventListener) {
    player.addEventListener('onStateChange', 'handlePlayerStateChange');
  }
  else {
    player.attachEvent('onStateChange', 'handlePlayerStateChange');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a function that checks periodically whether the buffering is continuing or not:

```
// set interval to something reasonable, 5 seconds?
var buffercheck = setInterval(bufferstatus, 5000);
function bufferstatus() {
  onPlayerBuffering: function(){ /* your code for a callback here */ },
}
```

Comment: sorry, I would need a callback function for not buffering anymore, not something that keeps checking  the onPlayerBuffering callback..
I appreciate your trying though!